# Why is svaha in Japanese sowaka?

Tags: etymology, onyomi

I know this is a more Chinese centered question, but, if svaha sounds more like suwaha, why is it transliterated sowaka? Or more straight to the point, why is it that the Chinese word sowaka might have derived from, sa po he, and in Middle Chinese I think sa ba ha, not suwaha, unless it didn't have those syllables/the pronunciation of suwaha or the way it was heard varied. One more part that connects to the question is how did those readings get converted into so, wa, and ka (how did those Chinese readings convert into Onyomi even though it's a more general question)

Comment: [It seems simply the reading of 薩婆訶](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8F%E3%83%BC). So, as you guessed, it is the question of why svaha is transcribed that way in Chinese.

Comment: By the way, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit_grammar#Phonology), which cites W.S. Allen (1953) "*Phonetics in ancient India*", Sanskrit consonant abstractly written as *v* (as in word *svāhā*) was pronounced as [w] in earlier Sanskrit (as in PIE, Latin etc.), and in later Sanskrit was pronounced as [ʋ] ([voiced labiodental approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labiodental_approximant)). There you can read more about [ʋ] and hear audio sample. Maybe [ʋ] sounded to Chinese people most similarly to [b].

Comment: Phonetically, Chinese and Sanskrit are very, very different.  Transliteration only gets you so far, particularly when there are no real good equivalents to choose from.  But also, that aside, we're talking here about transliterations of transliterations into languages whose phonetics today differ considerably from the phonetics of the "original" transliterations.  This is one of the reasons why research into Korean and Japanese is so informative about how Chinese may or may not have been pronounced centuries ago.  This is a fascinating topic.

Comment: Wait it's pronounced more like a v? Ohh thats why b is there but idk about the sa. The sa needs more investigation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about Japanese.

Comment: Ok do i post it in the chinese stack exchange edit: posted

Comment: (https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/55570/)